# How to achieve seamless Page navigation in WinRT?

Tags: c#, xaml, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

Whenever I seem to navigate from one Page to another in my Metro app, there is a "flash" where nothing is displayed - only the default background colour. How can I make the Frame.Navigate method transition properly? My app is quite Image heavy so I imagine part of it is down to the Image loading. I have tried with other apps though, and there seems to be similar issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I found was to use the WinRT XAML Toolkit, that has controls for AlternativePage and AlternativeFrame. I use an extended splash screen to Preload the MainPage and any pages the user may need to get to quickly - I then Preload other pages as and when they may become needed.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issues when working with an image intensive Metro app. The short of it is, I never found a way for a seamless, non-jarring transition, even when ordering loaded items and populating the appropriate elements through async calls.

What I wound up doing was applying a fade out effect to the first page's parent element, and a fade in effect on the second. It made the load more pleasant to the eye. Rather than the pop-in effect with images, there is a smooth transition. It does add a very short delay over the non-fading version, but it just seems more organic and appealing.

Comment: Ok, how did you go about that?

Comment: For my case, I simply created a StoryBoard with a DoubleAnimation that animated from UIElement.Opacity 1 to 0 for fade out, 0 to 1 for fade in, and applied it appropriately. There are also FadeOutThemeAnimation and FadeInThemeAnimation elements you can use, though I had more custom needs. Because my navigation is triggered on click, I tied my storyBoard.Begin() to the click, and the did the actual navigation on the storyboard completed event. The second page starts with an Opacity of 0 on the parent element, and executes the fade in storyboard in the page OnNavigatedTo event.

Comment: Once again, this was all for a Metro App. Here's a link for animating UI elements. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh452703.aspx

Comment: As an aside, my App is XAML/C#, but the same transitions could be done in JS/HTML5, if the same problem exists there.